# override one value with a new value gives value undefined

Tags: react-hooks

To summarize what I want to do:

> Update the state depending on the previous state

I have searched in vain for a solution to the above problems. Found 3 solutions, unfortunately without any success.

1)

```
const Form = (props) => {
  
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(0);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const incrementOne = {
      value: setNewValue((prevState) => {
        return {...prevState, newValue: newValue + 1}
      })
    };
    console.log(incrementOne);
  };
```

2. 

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const incrementOne = {
      
      value: setNewValue(newValue + 1),
    };
    console.log(incrementOne);
  };
```

3

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const incrementOne = {
      
      value: setNewValue(prevState => prevState + 1),
    };
    console.log(incrementOne);
  };
```

Thank you in advance for your time and effort

Sincerely
/ Peter

Answer (score 0):

In all your examples you are creating an object with a `value` property. You assume that is supposed to get it's value from calling set function returned by `useState`. However, the result of calling this function is updating the state, and re-rendering. The function itself doesn't return anything (`undefined`).

```
const incrementOne = {
  value: setNewValue((prevState) => {
    return {...prevState, newValue: newValue + 1}
  })
};
```

You should call the `setNewValue` function when you want to update the value. You can calculate the new state using the previous one:

```
setNewValue(newValue + 1);
```

Or use a functional update to avoid depending on the state directly:

```
setNewValue(prevState => prevState + 1);
```

Note that the new value is only available after the component re-renders.

Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Form = (props) => {
  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState(0);

  const submitHandler = () => {
    setNewValue(prevState => prevState + 1);
  };
  
  const incrementOne = {
    value: newValue,
  };

  console.log(incrementOne);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{newValue}</div>
     
      <button onClick={submitHandler}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help:) I forgot that the component needs to re-render first. Should I use spread operator for immutable update?

Comment: Primitives (numbers for example) are immutable by definition. If you need to update objects or arrays you can use spread.

Comment: Thanks @Ori:) I think I´ll use spread in my app